# Extract package.json version using shell script

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, docker, package.json

I'm trying to extract the value of the version field in package.json from the build.sh file. Is there a way to do this? Looks like i can use the below to do the extraction, but what if node is not available globally where i execute the build.sh file so looking for a generic way to exact the value from package.json into build.sh file.

```
VERSION=$(node -e "(function () { console.log(require('./package.json').version) })()")
```

Comment: On a side note, a more succinct way to get the version using node itself is `VERSION=$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So i went ahead and used the readJson function from http://dailyraisin.com/read-json-value-in-bash/ which perfectly fits my need here

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted... it's exactly what the OP was asking for. Maybe you should have moved the relavent content from the link:
`PKG_VERSION=\`node -p "require('./package.json').version"\``

Comment: That's exactly why. As of 2023, the link is returning a 503 and this answer would be completely useless without your comment.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210621232358/http://dailyraisin.com/read-json-value-in-bash/

Answer (score 24):

If you have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) installed, it's really easy:

```
jq -r .version package.json
```

Answer (score 23):

Credit to [metakermit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544059/metakermit)

```sh
NODE_VERSION=$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")
echo $NODE_VERSION
```

Comment: A minor thing but don't need the `-e` in addition to `-p` since according to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script) `-p` is  "Identical to -e but prints the result."

Answer (score 11):

If you really want to use shell script then simply try it

```sh
sed 's/.*"version": "\(.*\)".*/\1/;t;d' ./package.json
```

Comment: this worked for me: `grep version package.json | sed 's/.*"version": "\(.*\)".*/\1/'`

Answer (score 7):

This way you can get version from package.json file using `bash`

```
VERSION='';
re="\"(version)\": \"([^\"]*)\"";

while read -r l; do
    if [[ $l =~ $re ]]; then
        value="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
        VERSION="$value";
    fi
done < package.json;

echo $VERSION;
```

Comment: Wow, great! – How would you retrieve other values that are nested, e.g. author:{ email: ...} }?

Comment: @RobertWildling, this is bash regex check. if nested then too you just need to specify `re="\"(key)\": \"([^\"]*)\"";` it should work. e.g. `regexemail="\"(email)\": \"([^\"]*)\"";`. it should work. it will only work to give you if key & value both are string. If you need to parse as object, please use `jq`.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution using awk (Installed by default linux and mac).

```bash
awk -F'"' '/"version": ".+"/{ print $4; exit; }' package.json
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to your package.json in scripts

```
    "version": "echo $npm_package_version",
```

In the bash `VERSION=$(npm run version --silent)`

None of the other answers was good enough for my case, I searched on google and found [this](https://justinmchase.com/2016/08/29/getting-your-npm-package-version-from-bash/) its actually from 2016.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand where you are heading to, you are trying to version your artifact (Docker image in your case). Are you planning to manually bump the version (in package.json) every time when you have a checkin?

Instead, I would suggest you to use some automated solutions like [Nebula Release Plugin (In Java World)](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.nebula-release), I don't know anything similar exist in nodejs world. If none of this makes any sense to you, let me know, I will delete this answer :)